# jquery sliding menu "unslides" when jqueryui datepicker textbox selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a simple dropdown menu using jquery and jqueryui. (see a basic example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEE9Q/1/)).

Notice that the sliding all works, but when you click in the textbox of the Search dropdown and try to use the datepicker, the menu closes.

Can anyone please help me figure out how to keep that menu from closing when using the datepicker?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because on clicking the datepicker you are not hovering the menu anymore, thus toggeling the menu back again. The easiest way to avoid this (without rewriting the event handlers) is to add a .hover() function for the menu on clicking the date picker. Can't provide you the right script right now since i'm not on a pc.